# get checkbox selected value

Tags: javascript, checkbox, checked

I have multiple checkboxes that get generated by a php code and the HTML looks like this:

```
<input name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="firstBox" type="checkbox">
<input name="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="secondBox" type="checkbox">
```

However when I try to get the selected value by the user using below script

```
document.getElementById('checkbox').value
```

I always get 'firstBox' even when the secondBox is selected. Please help me solving this

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 3):

IDs are identifiers for specific elements. Therefore, they **must** be unique.

An alternative is setting the same name and use the function `querySelectorAll` to get the checked checkboxes.

**Use this selector to get the checked options:** `[name="checkbox"]:checked`

```js
document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var checked = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="checkbox"]:checked')); 
  checked.forEach(function(e) {
    console.log(e.value);  
  });  
});
```

```html
<input name="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="firstBox" type="checkbox">
<input name="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="secondBox" type="checkbox">

<button id='check'>Check</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

IDs must be unique.

```
<input name="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="firstBox" type="checkbox">
<input name="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="secondBox" type="checkbox">
```

Get value of first checkbox:

```
document.getElementById('checkbox1').value
```

Get value of second checkbox

```
document.getElementById('checkbox2').value
```

Comment: He's only interested in getting the checked checkboxes value.